# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Tags: python, typeerror, operand

```
name = input('Enter name here:')
pyc = input('enter pyc :')
tpy = input('enter tpy:')
percent = (pyc / tpy) * 100;
print (percent)
input('press enter to quit')
```

whenever i run this program i get this

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

what can i do to divide pyc by tpy?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

By turning them into integers instead:

```
percent = (int(pyc) / int(tpy)) * 100;
```

In python 3, the `input()` function returns a string. Always. This is a change from Python 2; the `raw_input()` function was renamed to `input()`.

Comment: Or, potentially, `float`s or `decimal.Decimal`s as appropriate, if you need to accept numbers that are not whole integers.

Answer (score 19):

The first thing you should do is learn to read error messages. What does it tell you -- that you can't use two strings with the divide operator.

So, ask yourself why they are strings and how do you make them not-strings. They are strings because all input is done via strings. And the way to make then not-strings is to convert them.

One way to convert a string to an integer is to use the [int](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) function. For example:

```
percent = (int(pyc) / int(tpy)) * 100
```

Answer (score 4):

There is another error with the forwars=d slash.

```
if we get this : def get_x(r): return path/'train'/r['fname']
is the same as def get_x(r): return path + 'train' + r['fname']
```

Comment: essentially - if you're concatenating paths with `/`, remove spaces between concatenated parts

Answer (score 1):

I would have written:

```
percent = 100
while True:
     try:
        pyc = int(input('enter pyc :'))
        tpy = int(input('enter tpy:'))
        percent = (pyc / tpy) * percent
        break
     except ZeroDivisionError as detail:
        print 'Handling run-time error:', detail
```

Comment: thanks, im new to programming and i never would have known to do this

Comment: If you're going to add in error handling, you probably want an `except ValueError` clause to handle invalid inputs…

Answer (score -1):

```
name = input ('What is your name?: ')
age = input('How old are you?: ')
date = input ('What year is it?: ')
year = (int(date) - int(age) + 100)

print('You\'ll be 100 in the year ', year)




#That's how I decided to hardcode it. You could get more specific with actual birthdates or else it'll probably be off by a year unless your bday passed.
```

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of two other answers to the question, and thus doesn't add anything useful to the post.