# unexpected TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x

The task is to write a program which asks the user to enter the total rainfall for each of the 12 months. The inputs will be stored in a list. The program should then calculate and display the total rainfall for the year, the average monthly rainfall, and the months with the highest and lowest amounts.

I am supposed to do this by using a loop that loops 20 times and appends each score to a list after it is entered. Please keep in mind that I am a beginner. Here's my code so far:

```
def main():

        months = [0] * 12
        name_months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun', \
                   'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']

        def total(months):
            total = 0
            for num in months:
                total += num
            return total

        for index in range(12):
            print('Please enter the amount of rain in')
            months[index] = input(name_months[index] + ': ')
        print('The total is'), total(months),'mm.'


        avarage = total(months) / 12.0
        print('The avarage rainfall is'), avarage,'mm.'

main()
```

Comment: Err... sorry, wrong duplicate. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235703/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-str is probably better)

Comment: This is a site for beginners and professionals alike. As long as you have at least attempted to find the solution yourself, no one is going to be rude.

Comment: @MartinKonecny thank you so much! im just trying so hard because i really like it. I took and 8 week course and its been difficult. Plus i heard there is not a lot of woman in the field and some men have not been so nice to me.

Answer (score 2):

This must be Python 3.  You have to convert the user input to numbers instead of strings:

```
# Sets months[index] to a string
months[index] = input(name_months[index] + ': ')
```

Should be:

```
# Sets months[index] to a (floating-point) number
months[index] = float(input(name_months[index] + ': '))
```

Comment: (And if it's Python 3, those `print()` statements with commas afterwards are... not going to work how you expect)

Comment: @Wooble it is python 3 :/

Comment: @wobble i did that and now it leaves my The total is 
The avarage rainfall is. leaves both blank

Comment: @wooble hanks sweetheart i think im getting it lil by little

Answer (score 1):

> Then the teacher asks to use a loop that loops 20 times and appends each score to a list after it is entered.

The 20 has got to be a typo unless you are supposed to use a very weird calendar. :)

Reason for the error:

You are initializing `total` to `0` but then try to add strings to it because `input` will return a string. You will have to convert your input to integer (or float) values first.

Suggestions to clean up your program:

```
months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
am = [int(input('input rainfall for {}: '.format(m))) for m in months]
comb = list(zip(months,am))
total = sum(am)
avg = total/12
least = min(comb, key=lambda x: x[1])
most = max(comb, key=lambda x: x[1])

print('month\tamount')
for mon, amount in comb:
    print('{0}\t{1}'.format(mon, amount))

print('total: {}'.format(total))
print('average: {}'.format(avg))
print('least rain in: {0} ({1})'.format(least[0], least[1]))
print('most rain in: {0} ({1})'.format(most[0], most[1]))
```

sample run:

```
input rainfall for Jan: 1
input rainfall for Feb: 2
input rainfall for Mar: 3
input rainfall for Apr: 4
input rainfall for May: 5
input rainfall for Jun: 6
input rainfall for Jul: 7
input rainfall for Aug: 8
input rainfall for Sep: 9
input rainfall for Oct: 10
input rainfall for Nov: 11
input rainfall for Dec: 12
month   amount
Jan     1
Feb     2
Mar     3
Apr     4
May     5
Jun     6
Jul     7
Aug     8
Sep     9
Oct     10
Nov     11
Dec     12
total: 78
average: 6.5
least rain in: Jan (1)
most rain in: Dec (12)
```

Comment: is this python 3? @timgeb

Comment: Thanks @timgeb Im only in chapter 8 and i cant remember seeing } in this book so far anyway its called starting with python.

Comment: @Esiswildflower some of the techniques I used will probably be covered later in your book (anonymous functions, generator/list comprehensions, zip, formatting strings, ...).

Comment: are any of them global?

Answer (score -2):

It is not possible to concatenate a String with an Integer using the `+` operator. You have to convert the Integer into a String using `str(int)`.

```
>>> 10 + '10'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: im not seeing this @christian berendt