# Working out percentage depending on user input

Tags: python, input, percentage

I want to make a program that creates the percentage of two numbers that are determined by the user's input, a use for this could be if you would like to find out the percentage you've gotten on a test ect. This is the code I've used in python but I continue to get the error message

"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'"

```
count = input("What is the amount of marks you got in your test?")
total = input("What is the total amount of marks in your test?")
percentage = count/total*100
print(percentage, + "%")
```

I've heard that percentage cannot be done on python version 3.5.0, although I don't know if this is true or not.

I'm running windows 10 and python 3.5.0

Comment: Just to answer the other question here, "... percentage cannot be done on python version 3.5.0 ..." is not correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235703/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-str)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert the input from `string` to `float`, as input comes in form of a `string`...

So do this before you use them in your computations

```
count = float(count)
total = float(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

you first need to convert count and total into floats:

```
while true:
    count = input("What is the amount of marks you got in your test?")
    total = input("What is the total amount of marks in your test?")

    try: #makes sure for valid input
         count = float(count)
         total = float(count)
         break
    except:
         print("Please input valid number")
```

you can then perform numeric operations:

```
percentage = count/total*100 #valid
print(str(percentage) + "%")#you had a comma when you didnt need it, and you need to convert back to string before concatenating
```