# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to programming and can't figure out how to fix this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aubreyoleary/Documents/Cashier.py", line 31, in <module>
    changePennies = int((amountReceived - amountDue) * 100)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

My code:

```
import math

class Cashier:

    def getDollars(self, x):
        return x / 100

    def getQuarters(self, x):
        y = x % 100
        return y / 25

    def getDimes(self, x):
        y = x % 100
        return y % 10

    def getNickels(self, x):
        y = x % 100
        return y % 5

    def getPennies(self, x):
        y = x * 1
        return y

while True:

    thecashier = Cashier()

    amountDue = input("Please enter amount due: ")
    amountReceived = input("Please enter amount received: ")

    changePennies = int((amountReceived - amountDue) * 100)

    print(thecashier.getPennies(changePennies))
    print(thecashier.getDollars(changePennies))
    print(thecashier.getQuarters(changePennies))
    print(thecashier.getDimes(changePennies))
    print(thecashier.getNickels(changePennies))

    choice = input("Do you want to continue <yes> <no>? ")
    if (choice == "no"):
        print("Have a nice day. ")
        break
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235703/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-str)

Answer (score 1):

That mean '6' - '4' won't work because they are both strings.  You first need to convert the string values to numbers:

```
changePennies = int(round((float(amountReceived) - float(amountDue)) * 100, 0))
```

Comment: Actually you need to use `int(round( ... ) )`. Floating point decimals do not store exactly as `int`s, and you will get floating point errors if you do not round before converting to an `int`, For example, on a 32-bit machine, if I type `print int(float('1.13')*100)`, I get an output of `112`. If I type `print int(round(float('1.13')*100))`, I get `113` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It is because data type of `amountReceived` and `amountDue` is string. You have to typecast it to `float` before you perform arithematic `-` operation.

Instead of `int((amountReceived - amountDue) * 100)`, use:

```
changePennies = int(float(amountReceived) - float(amountDue)) * 100
```

Comment: This does not work. `int( ... )` will give an error if the user inputs a decimal value.

Comment: You haven't provided the sample input. I used `int` as it was used in your code. I can't predict what kind value you are passing, and what kind of output you require :)

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly. Hope that will work.

Comment: I do not agree with to `round` the `float` value in order to generate the same result on 32/64 bit machines. With `round`, you are changing the precision of `float` value. One never has cluster of servers few with 32 bit machine & others with 64 bit machine. It is the behavior of python compiler. Let it behave the way it wants irrespective of 32 bit or 64 bit.

Comment: How are the result wrong? Considering the question, I do not think there is any need of using `round`, as round changed the exact value

Comment: Open your python console and type `int(float('1.13')*100)`. Now type `int(round(float('1.13')*100))`. What do you expect? What is the result? On my machine I get `112` for the first, and `113` for the second. This is why you need `round()`.