# i made a mistake while trying to solve the quadratic formula in python

Tags: python

im a beginner in python, can somebody help me what i did wrong here?

```
import math


def quadratgleichung(a,b,c):
    loesung1 = - (b/a)/2 + sqrt(    ((b/a)/2) * ((b/a)/2) - (c/a)   )
    loesung2 = - (b/a)/2 - sqrt(    ((b/a)/2) * ((b/a)/2) - (c/a)   )

    return loesung1, loesung2

a = input("Enter a.")
b = input("Enter b.")
c = input("Enter c.")

quadratgleichung(a,b,c)

print(f"Die Lösungen der eingegebenen quadratischen Gleichung sind {loesung1} und {loesung2} !\n")
```

this is what comes out in the console:
should i use different variable names in the function or were is the problem?

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-3207ceaf35b6> in <module>
     12 c = input("Enter c.")
     13 
---> 14 quadratgleichung(a,b,c)
     15 
     16 print(f"Die Lösungen der eingegebenen quadratischen Gleichung sind {loesung1} und {loesung2} !\n")

<ipython-input-11-3207ceaf35b6> in quadratgleichung(a, b, c)
      3 
      4 def quadratgleichung(a,b,c):
----> 5     loesung1 = - (b/a)/2 + sqrt(((b/a)/2) * ((b/a)/2) - (c/a))
      6     loesung2 = - (b/a)/2 - sqrt(((b/a)/2) * ((b/a)/2) - (c/a))
      7 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

thanks in advance!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235703/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-str)

Comment: Also, using `sqrt` rather than `math.sqrt` is a problem given your import statement, though you could use `from math import sqrt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by looking at the error, it looks like the variables `a`, `b` and `c` get sent as a string. Then your `quadratgleichung` method is trying to divide the string types, which it can't do.
Try to convert the `a`, `b`, and `c` to float before calling the `quadratgleichung`
`a = float(input("Enter a."))` and the same for `b` and `c`