# unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' issue

Tags: python, traceback

My code:

```py
a = input("Enter a number: ")
b = input("Enter another number: ")
int(a)
int(b)
if a == 0:
    print("You cannot divide a number by 0")
if b == 0:
    print("You cannot divide by 0")
else:
    print("The first number,", a, "divided by the second number,", b, "equals", a / b)
```

The error:

```
File "C:/Users/aaron/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 10, in <module>
    print("The first number,", a, "divided by the second number,", b, "equals", a / b)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

I have converted it to an integer (obviously not but I think I have!) but wondering where I'm wrong.

Comment: Please post the code as formatted text in the question itself, dont post links to code or images of code

Comment: write al your code in your question

Comment: Post the minimum number of lines of code that, if we copy and run it, will produce the error.

Comment: try inserting before the line that gives error: print(type(a), type(b))

Comment: `input` returns a `str`; you cannot divide two strings. `int(a)` itself *returns* an `int`; it does not reassign an int to the name `a`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235703/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-str

Comment: Not trying to be nitpicky, but why can't you divide 0 by a number?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235703/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-str)

Comment: b/a wil give ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the error what I reckon is that, you are trying to divide two strings.

If the variables a and b are taken as input and not hardcoded try using :

```
# to take the input 
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
```

If you are hardcoding the values of a and b, avoid the use of single or double quotes.
Using quotes makes the variable a string.

```
a = '12' # is a string and you can't perform division operation on this
a = 12 # is an integer
```

You can also convert the string into integer by:

```
a = int(a) # If initially variable a is a string
print("The first number,", a, "divided by the second number,", b, "equals", a / b)
```

This should work if both a and b are integers or floats.

Comment: thank you very much mate, this has fixed my problem and apologies for the vague question i posted at first, 10 years as a chef melts your brain haha

Answer (score 0):

try as 10

```
print("The first number,", a, "divided by the second number,", b, "equals", int(a) / int(b))
```

or

```
a = int(input("Enter a number: "))
b = int(input("Enter another number: "))
```

if you want more to learn give a look at:

[Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0):

```
int(a)/int(b)
```

or

```
a=int(a)
b=int(b)
and str(a) and str(b) in the text
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are trying to divide 2 strings. This is not possible because you can't divide text. You first have to convert them into numbers such as integers or floats.

You tried to do this:

```
int(a)
int(b)
```

However, this is not turning the variables from strings to integers because you are not assigning the result of the `int()` function to the variable.

Basically the `int()` function is returning a value that is just getting lost.

You can instead do this:

```
a = int(a)
a = int(b)
```

If you want you can do it in less lines like this:

```
a = int(input("Enter a number: "))
b = int(input("Enter another number: "))
```