# how to do division using inputs in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to improve at coding in python. I'm trying to do some division using given numbers from the user and it keeps on saying that its wrong. I have tried multiple things and nothing has worked. Here's the code:

```
print("welcome to division thing")

num1 = input("what's number1? ")

num2 = input("whats number2? ")

num = num2 / num1

print(num)
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jdoodle.py", line 4, in <module>
    num = num2 / num1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

Idk what to do, help.

Comment: ``input`` returns a string. You have to convert it to a number, e.g. ``num1 = int(input(...))`` or ``num1 = float(input(...))``

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235703/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-str)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert your operands (num1, num2) to integer.
To do so:

```
num = int("1") # 1
```

Thence, your code would be:

```
print("welcome to division thing")

num1 = input("what's number1? ")

num2 = input("whats number2? ")

num = int(num2) / int(num1)

print(num)
```

Or:

```
print("welcome to division thing")


num1 = int(input("what's number1? "))

num2 = int(input("whats number2? "))

num = num2 / num1

print(num)
```

Hope it would help. Have a nice day. Keep it up!

Comment: It worked! thank you!

Comment: @PHOEBECOMBS If the answer worked for you, please accept it (green checkmark)

Answer (score 0):

you should use this:

```py
print("welcome to division thing")

num1 = int(input("what's number1? "))

num2 = int(input("whats number2? "))

num = num2 / num1

print(num)
```